# PHP remove replace 3 characters after matched character

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

```
$str = "This product price is 23,39 and sale end after 29th June";
```

I need to replace two characters after `","` with `".-"`, so the output like:

```
This product price is 23.- and sale end after 29th June
```

I tried with but it remove last 3 characters:

```
 echo substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - 3);
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: A regex would be easier than `substr`. With `substr` you'll need to find the first occurance and use that in place of the `0`. e.g. `strpos`.

Comment: `$string` is not `$str`

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing in the code. The second line of code addresses a different string variable than the first. Also, you don't seem to search for `,`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I will try to select the string that needs to be replaced:

```
substr($str, strpos($str, ","), 3);
// Gives me ,39 - 3 characters from the ,.
```

And now I'll replace it with the `.--`

```
<?php
  $str = "This product price is 23,39 and sale end after 29th June";
  echo str_replace(substr($str, strpos($str, ","), 3), ".--", $str);
?>
```

This gives me an output:

```
This product price is 23.-- and sale end after 29th June
```

Is this what you need? This is simple and doesn't need a RegEx. Not sure if RegEx will be more efficient in this case. I would go about doing this way.

Comment: @user3783243 Ha ha ha... True that. I just added the more info.

Comment: @user3783243 Yay!